# Resilvering for data transfer?

Tags: linux, backup, freebsd, zfs

I currently have a production server with four drives in raidz2 and a backup server that is identical in configuration and hardware.

I'm currently doing a transfer of data using rsync between the production server and the backup server.

I'm finding that its painfully slow, even over LAN.

Idea: What if I remove two drives from the production server and place them in the backup server to resilver the backup server drives, and then have the backup server resilver its own two last two drives? Would that make the transfer go significantly faster -- Is this a smart idea? Anyone know how to do this (I'm worried that I might resilver and lose all my data if I issue the wrong commands).

Comment: Why not use the zfs send/receive commands?

Comment: Are you using FreeBSD or Linux? Or is one server running FreeBSD and the other Linux? Seems odd to tag the post with both.

Answer (score 2):

No. Don't do it. Any form of backup that revolves around intentionally failing an array or pool of disks is fraught and irresponsible.

If you could provide details about your rsync command line, what you're transferring, the connection between the servers and any other specifics, we may be able to help with a more robust solution.

Comment: I looked into it, as it turns out the connection is a 64k ISDN line which makes sense for the poor speeds. Hmmmm.

Comment: Copy to an external drive and ship it.